# NPM cache issue

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, cypress

I'm using jenkins for execute test cases based on cypress. I'm using kitchen sink example that provide by cypress in github repo https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/Jenkinsfile
But when i execute this in jenkins job i got error

npm ci

```
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/.npm"
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/.npm"
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/.npm"
npm ERR! code EACCES
```

For extra information :
Jenkins installed in my MAC OS and running in port 8080 ( default port ) and node js also installed in my local system with version 17.5.0

But dockerfile using in above repo example using cypress image in docker and install related dependency in container

Answer (score 1):

This can't be solved by any of the ways formulated in different answers. Only solution I have found is just by avoiding it by changing npm version. Current release of npm is `9.0.1` while the latest version is `8.92.2`. Follow the commands:

```
sudo npm i -g npm@9.0.1 && sudo npm i -g npx --force && sudo npx create-react-app app-name
```

I hope it will work, as it did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Before running `npm ci` try either one of the command:

```js
sudo npm cache clean --force //forcefully remove any npm folder before install
OR
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/.npm" //suggested by jenkins
```

Comment: Hi I still see this issue when i execute "npm cache clean --force" in jenkins file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bs2pAf78YOMX4ItU4oHB3pYuY-Q2FcRl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible you can check this repository that already provide by cypress https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

Comment: When i used this "sudo chown -R 501:20 "/.npm" then in jenkins show error, sudo not found